# Typesetting the Middle Four Interchange Law

Tags: lyx, xy-pic, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I would like to typeset the middle four interchange law of 2-categories. In `xypic`, I managed to typeset the following repulsive thing:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\xymatrix {
\text{Middle} & \text{Four} & \text{Interchange} & \text{Law:} &  &  & \;\rruppertwocell{\a}\ar[rr] &  & \;\rruppertwocell{\b}\ar[rr] &  & \;\\
\;\rruppertwocell{\a}\rrlowertwocell{\;\a^{\prime}}\ar[rr] &  & \circ\rruppertwocell{\b}\rrlowertwocell{\;\b^{\prime}}\ar[rr] &  & \; & = & \;\rrlowertwocell{\;\a^{\prime}}\ar[rr]\ar@/^{0.7pc}/@[white][rrrr]^{\bullet} &  & \;\rrlowertwocell{\;\b^{\prime}}\ar[rr] &  & \;
}
```

The spacing is horrific though. What I would like is something like this:

[image]

But I really don't know how to solve the spacing issues. I don't know `tikz` at all, but I wouldn't mind a solution using it as long as it doesn't require too much effort for me to work with.

Note - I work in LyX.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you used for these illustrations?

Comment: @Marijn added to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make two separate xymatrices and put them side by side in minipages. The second xymatrix contains three rows with the bullet as middle row, and the rows put closer together with `@R-2pc` (2 pica). MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,2cell,graph]{xy} \UseAllTwocells

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[l]{0.65\textwidth}
\xymatrix {
\txt{Middle} & \txt{Four} & \txt{Interchange} & \txt{Law:} &   \\
\;\rruppertwocell{\alpha}\rrlowertwocell{\;\alpha^{\prime}}\ar[rr] &  & \circ\rruppertwocell{\beta}\rrlowertwocell{\;\beta^{\prime}}\ar[rr] &  & \quad \; = 
} 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.35\textwidth}
\xymatrix@R-2pc{
\rruppertwocell{\alpha}\ar[rr] & & \rruppertwocell{\beta}\ar[rr] & & \\
 & & \bullet & &\\
\rrlowertwocell{\alpha^{\prime}}\ar[rr] & & \rrlowertwocell{\beta^{\prime}}\ar[rr] & & 
}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a version with use of [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\arrowtcupp}[2]{\arrow[bend left=50, ""{name=U, below,inner sep=1}]{#1}\arrow[Rightarrow,from=U,to=MU,"#2"]}
\newcommand{\arrowtclow}[2]{\arrow[bend right=50, ""{name=L,inner sep=1}]{#1}\arrow[Rightarrow,from=LM,to=L]{}[]{#2}} % if you want to change some parameter of the label.
\newcommand{\arrowtcmid}[2]{\arrow[""{name=MU,inner sep=1},""{name=LM,below,inner sep=1}]{#1}[pos=.1]{#2}}
\newcommand{\dummy}{\textcolor{white}{\bullet}}

\begin{document}
Middle Four Interchange Law:    

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm]
    \dummy \arrowtcmid{r}{} \arrowtcupp{r}{\alpha}\arrowtclow{r}{\alpha\smash'} & \circ \arrowtcmid{r}{} \arrowtcupp{r}{\beta}\arrowtclow{r}{\beta\smash'} & \dummy
\end{tikzcd}
=
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm, row sep=-.15cm]
\dummy \arrowtcmid{r}{}\arrowtcupp{r}{\alpha} & \dummy \arrowtcmid{r}{}\arrowtcupp{r}{\beta} & \dummy \\
& \bullet & \\
\dummy \arrowtcmid{r}{}\arrowtclow{r}{\alpha\smash'} & \dummy \arrowtcmid{r}{}\arrowtclow{r}{\beta\smash'} & \dummy
\end{tikzcd}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]